# Mongoose, update each value in array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: 'Some event',
  items: [{
     status: 'NEW',
     value: 'one'
  },{
     status: 'NEW',
     value: 'two'
  }]
}
```

I need to update each status to the PENDING

This is doesn't work(

```
findOneAndUpdate({ _id: event.id },
{
 $set: {
   'items.$.status': "PENDING",
 },
},
{
  new: true,
  upsert: true,
}),
```

The main idea that i need to update each status field without any conditions because I already have the needed item and it just update status before next action.

Comment: you can apply `$` reference for all the elements by `$[]`, try `'items.$[].status': "PENDING",`.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply `$` reference for all the elements by `$[]`, try `'items.$[].status': "PENDING",`

Thanks [@turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal)!